# Meteor Angular get all users

Tags: angular, meteor

I am new to Meteor and Angular 2 and I am struggling with listing all of the users in my client. As far as I understood, I have to publish on my server and subscribe on my client, which I did the following way:

**users.ts**

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.publish('usersList', function () {
    console.log('Publish from server ');
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: {$ne: Meteor.userId()}});
});
```

However, this is not even called. I am importing this file in my **main.ts**. I am not sure how I should publish them in order to get all of the users.

I have created another collection by following the [Meteor-Angular2 tutorial](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/privacy-and-publish-subscribe-functions). The file is the following:
**wishes.ts**

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {Wishes} from '../../../both/collections/wishes.collection';

Meteor.publish('wishList', function () {
    console.log("wishlist "+this.userId);
    return Wishes.find(buildQuery.call(this));
});


function buildQuery(): Object {
    const isAvailable = {
        $and: [{
            owner: this.userId
        }, {
            owner: {
                $exists: true
            }
        }]
    }
    return isAvailable;
}
```

I call it in my **main.ts** in the server and it is working. I have no idea why one of the files is being called and why the other is not. Any direction will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The meteor publish method in your users.ts will get its callback triggered for every new client that subscribes to 'userList'. 
If you want to get all of the users in the Meteor users collection a simple find({}) will give you all the users, while if any more specific queries are needed you would use the in the find query to find one or more users.

Your code looks fine from the code snippets you have put in the post.

Comment: Unfortunately, Meteor.users.find({}) in the client (after subscribing to 'userList') returns only the current logged in user.

Comment: The client will receive the users from the servers Meteor.users.find({}) if you create a collection of them accessible by the client side, or send a message with them to client side directly. 
If you use Meteor.users.find({}) on the client side, it will return your current user, as it has no knowledge of the rest :).